# video inline iOS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, video

I am looking at implementing inline videos pre `iOS10`.

I have been looking at using [this library](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video)

This works for inline videos on `iOS10`, but not for pre `iOS10`.

I am using v 8.3 of iOS and v600.1.4 of safari

My **js** looks like this

```
var video = $('video').get(0);
makeVideoPlayableInline(video);

video.addEventListener('touchstart', function () {
   video.play();
});
```

And the **html** looks like this

```
<video src='http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4' class="video-player video-one" id="video-background" autoplay muted playsinline>
</video>
```

**CSS**

```
.IIV::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 5px;
}
```

Comment: There was a [bug in this version.](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video/issues/99) It's fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Have you include iphone-inline-video.browser.js like in the demo here : https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video/blob/master/demo/index.html ?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>iphone-inline-video demo with playsinline</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="../dist/iphone-inline-video.browser.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

Have you also check the JS console in your browser ?